# convert Bouncy Castle's AsymmetricCipherKeyPair (RSA) to java.security.KeyPair

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, jce

I am trying to automate generation of CA and certificates for our E2E testing. I started with Bouncy Castle and I have managed to generate CA cert and machine cert. However, now I need to convert the RSA keypair represented by BC' `org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` to `java.security.KeyPair`. I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably more than one way to do it, but here is one example:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PrivateKeyInfoFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory;

import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;


private static KeyPair convertBcToJceKeyPair(AsymmetricCipherKeyPair bcKeyPair) throws Exception {
    byte[] pkcs8Encoded = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.createPrivateKeyInfo(bcKeyPair.getPrivate()).getEncoded();
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8Encoded);
    byte[] spkiEncoded = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.createSubjectPublicKeyInfo(bcKeyPair.getPublic()).getEncoded();
    X509EncodedKeySpec spkiKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(spkiEncoded);
    KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return new KeyPair(keyFac.generatePublic(spkiKeySpec), keyFac.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec));
}
```